# how to make a list of functions execute in python?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to save the results of 10 function calls into a list. however, when I want to access this numerical data, I keep getting type errors, because the list is really a list of function calls. How do I make it do stuff so I can have numbers to do compare?

I tried setting temp variable to result of each spot in the list, but it still shows as a function.

Output should show the average for different # of dice, and return the best amount of dice to roll

```
def calculator(fn, num_samples=1000): # this is the function I'm trying to call
    def print_and_return(*args):
            total3 = 0
            for _ in range(num_samples):
                total3 += (fn(*args))
            return float(total3)/num_samples
        return print_and_return

def find_average(dice=six_sided):
    avglist = []
    k, spot = 0, 0
    bob = roll_dice(k+1, dice)
    passed_function = calculator(bob, 1000)

    print(passed_function)
    while k <= 10:
        avglist.append((passed_function)) # <==trying to save the results when I check with 1-10 dice rolls
        if k == 0:
            spot = 1
        else:
            temp = 0
            max = 0
            i = 0
            while i <= len(avglist):
                temp = avglist[i]
                if max > temp:
                    max = temp
                i +=1

            if (avglist[k] > temp):
                spot = k
        print(k, "dice scores", avglist[k], "on average")
        k +=1 
    return spot
```

Comment: Can you please show the code with sample data?

Comment: What does "it showed up as a function" mean?

Comment: What is `return print_and_return` supposed to do?

Comment: Does `roll_dice` return a function as well? The answers below are correct in saying that you need to *call* `passed_function` (inside the `while` loop, most likely with `k` as an argument), but even if you do, your code will not work if `bob` is not a function: You are passing `bob` as the `fn` argument to calculator, and inside `print_and_return`, `fn` is *applied* to an arg list (i.e., it is used as a function). Therefore, if `bob` is e.g. an `int` or a `float`, you will get a `TypeError` when trying to add the result of `fn(*args)` to `total3` (line 5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not *calling* `passed_function`. Calling a function with no arguments still reqires the `()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `calculator` function returns a function, not a plain value. You therefore need to call  `passed_function` in order to get your result.

Based on the arguments to your call to `roll_dice`, it looks like you want the `k` argument to vary in the loop. As written now, it will not. I suspect you are tripping yourself up a bit. The code could be written a whole lot simpler without so many function references being passed around.